# How to populate value in column based on condition using numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I am trying to populate new column with fixed value, if condition is met.
But i am also getting the value if condition is not met.(for some rows)
Where am i going wrong ?
I need blank in 'type' if 'id' is blank, else the string 'A2A'
datatype of column'ID1' is object. It gives error when i convert it into string.
Although we see blank rows in 'ID1'. It is displaying error "cannot perform operation on float"

Code:

```
df1['type'] = np.where((df1['ID1'].isnull()) , np.nan,'A2A')
```

input:

```
ID1



2
3


4
```

ouput:

```
ID1 type
    nan
    A2A
    A2A
2   A2A
3   A2A
    nan
    nan
4   A2A
    A2A
```

Expected output:

```
ID1 type
    
    
    
2   A2A
3   A2A
    
    
4   A2A
```

Comment: What does `df1['ID1'].isnull()` output?

Comment: @ anky : yes they are blank spaces ' '

Comment: @Dan : output of `df1['ID1'].isnull()` shows True for blank/Null cells and also False for blank/null cells

Comment: @anky: it is displaying 'nan' for all rows

Comment: @anky : do you mean `df1['ID1'].to_dict()` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

Make sure you remove multiple empty spaces to just empty

```
df = pd.DataFrame([None, np.nan, '','','',2,3,'',''])

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', '', regex=True)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

**Option 1: You can use pandas `.apply`**

```
df["type"] = df.apply(lambda x: "A2A" if x[0] else '',axis=1)
```

**Option 2: without axis:**

```
df["type"] = df[0].apply(lambda x: "A2A" if x else '')
```

**Option 3: You can also use `np.where`:**

```
df["type"] = np.where(df[0], "A2A", '')
```

**Option 4: Convert entire column in string format and check values**

```
df[0].apply(lambda x: "A2A" if str(x).lower().strip() not in ["none","nan",""] else '')
```

Input:

```
    0
0   None
1   NaN
2   
3   
4   
5   2
6   3
7   
8
```

output:

```
    0   type
0       
1       
2       
3       
4       
5   2   A2A
6   3   A2A
7       
8
```

Comment: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: @Anonymus, can you try other options

Comment: @anky, I've tried with np.nan, None, empty spaces as well.

Comment: 'ID1' is an output aftering using  'df.merge' on two columns, so the datatype is 'object' would that matter ?

Comment: @Anonymus, It doen't matter what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Narendra Prasath : after using option 2 and option 3. i am getting the same output which i was getting earlier 'A2A' is populated even when condition is NOT met. (for some rows)

Comment: @Anonymus, can you try this, `df[0].apply(lambda x: "A2A" if str(x).lower().strip() not in ["none","nan",""] else '')`

Comment: @Narendra Prasath: works fine now, why are we using str.lower () and str.strip () ? even when we see only digits in it ?

Comment: @Anonymus I am converting all the columns to string becasue if multiple spaces or None or NaN also get converted to string. just why I am checking with list of empty element to not match. Let me update this solution as well. Please upvote if you find useful. You can play with removing some values in the list `["none","nan",""]` and see where it actually getting wrong results.

Comment: Gosh , upvoted your efforts.. however the question should have been better (mcve), comments are helpful unless people read them